# Como obtener un certificado https para mi pagina alojada en AWS S3 ( Dominio en NIC.ar)

Tags: angular, https, aws, amazon-s3

Hola a toda la comunidad, primero que nada, frente a mi desesperacion he publicado esta misma pregunta en otros foros.

Comencemos:

Tengo alojado en un Bucket (AWS S3) una pagina web enlazada con un dominio registrado en NIC.ar ('Argentina' valga la redundancia). Ok hasta ahi todo bien.
La pagina hace uso de los servicios de autenticacion de FACEBOOK Y GOOGLE, por ende necesito urgente que mi pagina trabaje bajo el protocolo **HTTPS**.
Bien, entonces **ESPECIFICAMENTE** el problema seria conseguir esos certificados y poder usarlos en AMAZON (AWS) donde tengo alojada mi pagina en un bucket s3.
Investigando un poco, con alguno de los siguientes servicios: **ROUTE 53 - CLOUDFRONT - S3** puedo obtener el certificado. pero **NO PUEDO VALIDARLO** ya que el certificado genera valores CNAME record y en NIC.ar solamente puedo delegar valoes NS record.

Se entiende el problema? es urgente porfavor.

Comment: 1. Puedes instalar directamente en tu VPS en este caso la instancia de AWS el free SSL de https://letsencrypt.org/es/ y hacer la respectiva configuración de NGINX oo Apache dependiendo del servidor que utilices. 2. Puedes utilizar los que te da Cloudflare puedes averiguar si por medio de DNS y luego activas SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar comprar tu certificado en cualquier vendor y luego subirlo a aws con el servicios ACM (https://aws.amazon.com/es/certificate-manager/).

ya cuando tengas tu certificado alli puedes usarlo sin problema desde cloudfront.

Importante subirlo en la region de virginia (us-east-1) para poderlo usar desde cloudfront.